# Create a dynamic request from increasing value of variables in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

```
I have a response from one request as :

**{  
   "Packages":[  
      {  
         "CreatedBy":"Administrator",
         "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1535635263383)\/",
         "DeviceFamily":6,
         "LastVersion":{  
            "BuildVersion":"1.0",
            "Comment":"",
            "ExtraSize":0,
            "InstallPrompt":false,
            "OSVersion":"2.0-10.0",
            "Processor":"ALL",
            "Size":10465294,
            "UploadDate":"\/Date(1535635263520)\/",
            "UploadedBy":"Administrator",
            "Vendor":"",
            "Version":"1.0"
         },
         "Name":"10MB",
         "ReferenceId":"150e6517-f805-4e33-936f-d923657be79a",
         "TotalVersions":1
      },
      {  
         "CreatedBy":"Administrator",
         "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1535635276557)\/",
         "DeviceFamily":6,
         "LastVersion":{  
            "BuildVersion":"1.0",
            "Comment":"",
            "ExtraSize":0,
            "InstallPrompt":false,
            "OSVersion":"2.0-10.0",
            "Processor":"ALL",
            "Size":104884390,
            "UploadDate":"\/Date(1535635277457)\/",
            "UploadedBy":"Administrator",
            "Vendor":"",
            "Version":"1.0"
         },
         "Name":"100MB",
         "ReferenceId":"02e94794-2e0a-4c20-9d20-5612a9b2378f",
         "TotalVersions":1
      }
   ],
   "Total":2
}**
```

The above json contains value of two ReferenceId , Name , Version and Size.
These values need to be passed into the successive request and create dynamic request in a way that the request can modify if the value for above variables increases to 4,6 or N.

```
I have to pass values in next request as :

**{  
   "HasDraftVersion":false,
   "IsApprovalPending":null,
   "IsInstalledSilently":true,
   "LastModified":"/Date(1535570626907)/",
   "LastModifiedBy":"Administrator",
   "DeviceConfigurations":[  
   ],
   "Packages":[  
      {  
         "ReferenceId":"b0f3b725-86f9-4bc3-a929-63bfb8e8727c",
         "Name":"10MB",
         "Version":"1.0",
         "PackageDependencies":"",
         "Size":10465294
      },
      {  
         "ReferenceId":"bb6b3176-0798-4cef-9659-4a119470a4dc",
         "Name":"100MB",
         "Version":"1.0",
         "PackageDependencies":"",
         "Size":104884390
      }
   ],
   "LdapTargets":null,
   "ReferenceId":null,
   "DeviceFamily":6,
   "DeviceFamilyQualification":0,
   "Name":"test",
   "Description":"",
   "Random":"2018-08-29T15:16:47",
   "IsPublicAPI":true
}**
```

**How to create a dynamic request with increase in value in previous json?

I am trying with Json path extractor but unable to create dynamic request.

I am also trying with Regular expression extractor.**

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of 2nd request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def previousResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData())

   @groovy.transform.Immutable
   class Package {
       String ReferenceId
       String Name
       String Version
       Integer Size
   }

   def packages = previousResponse.Packages.collect { Package -> new Package(Package.ReferenceId, Package.Name, Package.LastVersion.Version, Package.LastVersion.Size) }

   def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

   builder(HasDraftVersion: false,
           IsApprovalPending: null,
           IsInstalledSilently: true,
           LastModified: "/Date(1535570626907)/",
           LastModifiedBy: "Administrator",
           DeviceConfigurations: [],
           Packages: packages.collect() {
               [
                       ReferenceId        : it.ReferenceId,
                       Name               : it.Name,
                       Version            : it.Version,
                       PackageDependencies: "",
                       Size               : it.Size
               ]
           },
           LdapTargets: null,
           ReferenceId: null,
           DeviceFamily: 6,
           DeviceFamilyQualification: 0,
           Name: "test",
           Description: "",
           Random: "2018-08-29T15:16:47",
           IsPublicAPI: true)

   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
   ```

The above code will automatically extract the required values from the previous response, dynamically build request using the values and add it to the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body.

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy: JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri.

Comment: when I am implementing the above code there are few points I observed as:1. The labels are not in capital letters like the first alphabet of ReferenceId. 2. I am getting some after implementing as : {"Data":null,"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":"Parameter 'ReferenceId' has invalid value ''.","HelpLink":null,"InnerErrors":[{"Data":["ReferenceId",""],"ErrorCode":2,"ErrorMessage":"Parameter 'ReferenceId' has invalid value ''.","HelpLink":null,"InnerErrors":null,"Ref":"2018-08-30 12:12:22.5361-04:00"}],"Ref":"2018-08-30 12:12:22.5361-04:00"}

Comment: As an exception I amended the code to generate the required output, going forward be aware that SO is not a code-writing service and people contribute here as volunteers. If you need support consider using i.e. freelancing platforms. You might also would like to check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article